# How do I make a saved number for a survay?

Tags: javascript, html

Im very new to html an js and searching didnt got me the answer. My problem is that i want to make by a click on a button a variable change +1 so that it doesnt go back on a reload, to that i want that this number can be displayed on another site.
My tests:
the button to change the number: answer 1out of 4

```js
let A1 = '1';
function Antwort1(){
var A1 = 'A1' + 1
}
function resultA1(){
document.write(A1)  
}
```

```css
ul{font-family: arial;}
span, table, ul, p, p3, p2, h3, h1, h2, a, button{text-align: center; margin:auto ; font-family: arial; :}
p{margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;}
h1{text-decoration: underline; font-size: 4em ; background-color: lightblue}
h3{ font-size: 2em;}
p{font-size: 24px}
p2{font-size: 18px}
body{background: white}
button{font-size: 27px ; float: center ; cursor: pointer ; background-color: lightblue ; color : black ; border: solid white}
button:hover {font-size: 27px ; float: center ; cursor: pointer ; background-color: white ; color : lightblue ; border: solid lightblue}
p3{text-align: center}
.container{margin: auto; border: none ; display:grid; align-items:center  ;justify-contend: center}
```

```html
<html>

<script src="../index.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..\formate.css" >
<link rel="script" href="../index.js"
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Frage 1</h1>
    <h2>wie oft hast du online Unterricht, anstatt Aufgaben?</h2>
<p>
<button id="A1" onclick="Antwort1()">nie</button>

</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: We can't answer questions that amount to "build this for me". Please may you share what you have tried so far as a [mre], and also what specifically you're struggling with?

Comment: You need some backend service (i.e. a server with a basic database) to store this value.

Comment: Why do you mix forward and backward slashes in href attributes?

Comment: Syntax error in `var A1 +=`. There is no assignment value.

Comment: the back and forward slashes are different because i wanted to see if anything changes(it doesnt)